# Postfix, Dovecot problems, root logins from unknown ip`s

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have a problem with either Postfix, Dovecot or both configuration.
Everything works as it should, but in the logs i noticed that multiple different ip`s are sending mails using root account, they are trying to send from root@domain.com to root@domain.com. 
Im on Debian 9, removed my root login with:

> sudo passwd -d root

And disabled the account:

> sudo passwd -l root

There is one more account on the server and i noticed that that was accessed too! When i cheked auth.log there were no brute force attempts. I am running ssh on different port, using keys, plus iptables is set on that port with hitcount.

My Postfix version is: 3.1.12, Dovecot: 2.2.27 
Sample log from mail.log

```
Jan 20 18:37:50 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5026]: connect from unknown[122.228.19.79]
Jan 20 18:37:50 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5029]: connect from unknown[122.228.19.79]
Jan 20 18:37:50 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5026]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[122.228.19.79]
Jan 20 18:37:50 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5026]: disconnect from unknown[122.228.19.79] commands=0/0
Jan 20 18:37:51 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5029]: lost connection after UNKNOWN from unknown[122.228.19.79]
Jan 20 18:37:51 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5029]: disconnect from unknown[122.228.19.79] ehlo=1 unknown=0/1 commands=1/2
Jan 20 18:41:11 vps22525 postfix/anvil[5028]: statistics: max connection rate 2/60s for (submission:122.228.19.79) at Jan 20 18:37:50
Jan 20 18:41:11 vps22525 postfix/anvil[5028]: statistics: max connection count 2 for (submission:122.228.19.79) at Jan 20 18:37:50
Jan 20 18:41:11 vps22525 postfix/anvil[5028]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jan 20 18:37:50
Jan 20 19:54:48 vps22525 postfix/smtpd[5172]: warning: hostname ip-38-56.ZervDNS does not resolve to address 92.118.38.56: Name or service not known
Jan 20 19:54:48 vps22525 postfix/smtpd[5172]: connect from unknown[92.118.38.56]
Jan 20 19:54:52 vps22525 postfix/smtpd[5172]: disconnect from unknown[92.118.38.56] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Jan 20 19:58:12 vps22525 postfix/anvil[5174]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:92.118.38.56) at Jan 20 19:54:48
Jan 20 19:58:12 vps22525 postfix/anvil[5174]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:92.118.38.56) at Jan 20 19:54:48
Jan 20 19:58:12 vps22525 postfix/anvil[5174]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jan 20 19:54:48
Jan 20 21:24:32 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5303]: warning: hostname ip-178-112-68-164.static.contabo.net does not resolve to address 164.68.112.178: Name or service not known
Jan 20 21:24:32 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5303]: connect from unknown[164.68.112.178]
Jan 20 21:24:33 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5303]: SSL_accept error from unknown[164.68.112.178]: lost connection
Jan 20 21:24:33 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5303]: lost connection after STARTTLS from unknown[164.68.112.178]
Jan 20 21:24:33 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5303]: disconnect from unknown[164.68.112.178] ehlo=1 starttls=0/1 commands=1/2
Jan 20 21:25:08 vps22525 dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 1 secs): user=<>, rip=122.228.19.79, lip=127.127.127.127, TLS, session=<NdzXP5ech3d65BNP>
Jan 20 21:27:53 vps22525 postfix/anvil[5305]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (submission:164.68.112.178) at Jan 20 21:24:32
Jan 20 21:27:53 vps22525 postfix/anvil[5305]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (submission:164.68.112.178) at Jan 20 21:24:32
Jan 20 21:27:53 vps22525 postfix/anvil[5305]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jan 20 21:24:32
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/pickup[5421]: 2771B209A0: uid=0 from=<root>
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/cleanup[5533]: 2771B209A0: message-id=<20200120220003.2771B209A0@mail.mydomain.com>
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/qmgr[1453]: 2771B209A0: from=<root@mydomain.com>, size=1906, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/local[5535]: 2771B209A0: to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file /root/Mail$
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/cleanup[5533]: 2DED5209A5: message-id=<20200120220003.2DED5209A5@mail.mydomain.com>
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/qmgr[1453]: 2DED5209A5: from=<>, size=4037, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/bounce[5536]: 2771B209A0: sender non-delivery notification: 2DED5209A5
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/qmgr[1453]: 2771B209A0: removed
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/local[5535]: 2DED5209A5: to=<root@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file /root/Maildir/tmp/1579557603.P5535.vps$
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/qmgr[1453]: 2DED5209A5: removed
Jan 21 00:33:07 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5582]: warning: hostname zg-0911b-52.stretchoid.com does not resolve to address 159.203.193.36: Name or service not known
Jan 21 00:33:07 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5582]: connect from unknown[159.203.193.36]
Jan 21 00:33:07 vps22525 postfix/submission/smtpd[5582]: disconnect from unknown[159.203.193.36] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
Jan 21 00:36:27 vps22525 postfix/anvil[5584]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (submission:159.203.193.36) at Jan 21 00:33:07
Jan 21 00:36:27 vps22525 postfix/anvil[5584]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (submission:159.203.193.36) at Jan 21 00:33:07
Jan 21 00:36:27 vps22525 postfix/anvil[5584]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jan 21 00:33:07
Jan 21 03:09:01 vps22525 postfix/pickup[5713]: 557E6201DE: uid=0 from=<root>
Jan 21 03:09:01 vps22525 postfix/cleanup[5847]: 557E6201DE: message-id=<20200121010901.557E6201DE@mail.mydomain.com>
Jan 21 03:09:01 vps22525 postfix/qmgr[1453]: 557E6201DE: from=<root@mydomain.com>, size=1048, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 21 03:09:01 vps22525 postfix/local[5849]: 557E6201DE: to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file /root/Mail$
Jan 21 03:09:01 vps22525 postfix/cleanup[5847]: 5F945209B4: message-id=<20200121010901.5F945209B4@mail.mydomain.com>
Jan 21 03:09:01 vps22525 postfix/qmgr[1453]: 5F945209B4: from=<>, size=3179, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 21 03:09:01 vps22525 postfix/bounce[5850]: 557E6201DE: sender non-delivery notification: 5F945209B4
Jan 21 03:09:01 vps22525 postfix/qmgr[1453]: 557E6201DE: removed
Jan 21 03:09:01 vps22525 postfix/local[5849]: 5F945209B4: to=<root@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file /root/Maildir/tmp/1579568941.P5849.vps$
Jan 21 03:09:01 vps22525 postfix/qmgr[1453]: 5F945209B4: removed
```

Postfix main.cf

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
mydomain = mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $mydomain
masquerade_domains = $mydomain
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
#mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access  hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access reject_unknown_recipient_domain permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination,reject_invalid_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_sender_domain,reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,reject_invalid_helo_hostname,reject_unknown_helo_hostname
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 5
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 10
smtpd_restriction_classes = mua_sender_restrictions,
    mua_client_restrictions,
    mua_helo_restrictions
mua_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
mua_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
mua_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
    reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    permit
```

How do i prevent this from happening ? What did i miss in my configuration

> EDIT

Thank you all for help. As @Piotr P. Karwasz mention it was a cron daemon...

Answer (score 0):

They are trying to send mail through your mail system. But judging from the logs provided, the mail isn't going through. Which is a good thing!
You generally do not want to relay mail for other domains, since that's being used mostly by spammers and which will generally get your mailserver blacklisted.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay for more info.

All in all, you can ignore this. Or if you really want, you can block them. Refer to google for more info on that.

Answer (score 0):

These messages are locally generated by a process running as **root**:

```
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/pickup[5421]: 2771B209A0: uid=0 from=<root>
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/cleanup[5533]: 2771B209A0: message-id=<20200120220003.2771B209A0@mail.mydomain.com>
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/qmgr[1453]: 2771B209A0: from=<root@mydomain.com>, size=1906, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/local[5535]: 2771B209A0: to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file /root/Mail$
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/cleanup[5533]: 2DED5209A5: message-id=<20200120220003.2DED5209A5@mail.mydomain.com>
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/qmgr[1453]: 2DED5209A5: from=<>, size=4037, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/bounce[5536]: 2771B209A0: sender non-delivery notification: 2DED5209A5
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/qmgr[1453]: 2771B209A0: removed
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/local[5535]: 2DED5209A5: to=<root@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file /root/Maildir/tmp/1579557603.P5535.vps$
Jan 21 00:00:03 vps22525 postfix/qmgr[1453]: 2DED5209A5: removed
```

Probably it is the `CRON` daemon. The message and the bounce message fail to be delivered, because **root** does not have a mailbox. Add an [alias](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html) from root to your account in `/etc/aliases` to be able to receive these e-mails.

Comment: First of all Thank you for your help! I havent payed too much attention at the timestamps, but by the looks of it you might be right. I have added my username to /etc/aliases will report on changes

Comment: Thanks @Piotr it was as you said